# How to create the table using command in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have installed SQL Server 2005.

I am creating my table like this:

- open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- create the database
- then create the table (right click on Tables, create a new table) then it show the table UI.

Can I create the table using command in SQL Server 2005 ?

For example using:

```
create table emp (emp_id varchar2(10)  NOT NULL,basic_salary varchar2(10) NOT NULL);
```

please help where I use this command to create the table.

Comment: Why is this tagged with mysql?

Comment: @user783160: you run TSQL scripts in sql server management studio

Comment: Yes, please use a query window for DDL, not the UI wizards which are full of bugs and unintuitive behavior IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Yes **of course** you can do this!

In SQL Server Management Studio, select (or create) the database for your table, then:

1. select `New Query` (either from the toolbar, or from `File > New > New Query using current connection`)
2. type in (or copy&paste in) your T-SQL statement
3. run that statement (menu: `Query > Execute` or equivalent keyboard shortcut)

and you're done!

Comment: @user783160: Please get in the habit of **accepting** the best answer provided, the one solving your problem. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)